# How to fix ? Wood railing & balusters on front porch

Tags: porch, railing

I don’t know why this was done,maybe laziness. How can I remove staples from 2x4 railing? I need to correct this so I can begin sanding,etc. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type of staples?  Paper type, construction type, or fence stables.

Comment: what have you tried? ... how did the attempt fail?

Comment: crip656I assume construction staples.

Comment: I’ve not tried anything yet. Just research‍♀️

Comment: How about a picture since we're not good at assuming.. lol

Comment: How do I add pic‍♀️

Comment: Sorry! I’ll be back when I figure out how to add pics

Comment: Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image or link

Comment: The edit button should show a mountain, that is suppose to be good for pictures.  Imagine to remove the staples will need to get underneath the cross piece and pry up carefully.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add pics (you can't add them here in the comments).

Comment: My guess, start by trying to work a sharp kitchen knife under the staple.  You might need to gouge slightly into the wood.  The next step would be a slim screwdriver.  Or, maybe you could pull the staple out by grabbing it with some grabbers -- similar to pliers but different shape -- not sure what they're called.